# periodic crashes in cl.exe, kernelbase.dll

Tags: visual-studio, jenkins, waf

I frequently have the following crash from cl.exe. This happens both when compiling and running other a help command on cl. This is happening on Windows Server 2008, but I think this happens sometimes on Windows XP also. This is occurring very frequently within Jenkins when when running `waf configure`.

I haven't been able to find anything online to fix this problem, although there are mentions of kernelbase.dll crashing in other programs.

Does anyone have any thoughts on how to avoid this problem?

Thanks

```
    Log Name:      Application
    Source:        Application Error
    Date:          1/24/2012 4:25:51 PM
    Event ID:      1000
    Task Category: (100)
    Level:         Error
    Keywords:      Classic
    User:          N/A
    Computer:      
    Description:
    Faulting application name: cl.exe, version: 15.0.30729.1, time stamp: 0x488ef6ea
    Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7600.16385, time stamp: 0x4a5bdbdf
    Exception code: 0x0eedfade
    Fault offset: 0x0000b727
    Faulting process id: 0xd74
    Faulting application start time: 0x01ccdae720a1cbbd
    Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe
    Faulting module path: C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
    Report Id: 5e9f206e-46da-11e1-a28d-bc305bd1c68c
    Event Xml:
    
      
        
        1000
        2
        100
        0x80000000000000
        
        55240
        Application
        
        
      
      
        cl.exe
        15.0.30729.1
        488ef6ea
        KERNELBASE.dll
        6.1.7600.16385
        4a5bdbdf
        0eedfade
        0000b727
        d74
        01ccdae720a1cbbd
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe
        C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
        5e9f206e-46da-11e1-a28d-bc305bd1c68c
```

Comment: Is there any reason you have added the jenkins tag? Does this happen only in Jenkins, or while running cl through cmd also?

Comment: I don't know for sure that it happens only in Jenkins, but that is the only place I've seen it and haven't heard of any developers experiencing it.

I just don't know what combinations of things could be causing this, so I assumed it could be anything.

Answer (score 1):

Check:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/05764562-0133-4e6d-a613-bfe1ec2f0c1d/.

This seems to be an issue with updated dlls. I would also suggest compiling your program outside of Jenkins just to be sure that it is not an issue with Jenkins (either paths, or anything else).